# Retrive JSON from body in a POST request POSTMAN

Tags: php, postman

I have a problem receiving the body of a POST call from Postman, but it could be from other channels as well.
The Headers I recover them without problems but the JSON in the body always keeps returning NULL or an empty array.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you
alby696

```
$payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
$receivedHeaders = getRequestHeaders();
$myPostArgs = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);

var_dump($_POST);

var_dump(json_decode($payload,true));

var_dump($myPostArgs);
```

[image: Postman]

Comment: Your code shows 3 `var_dump` calls, but your screenshot only shows two outputs. Is that definitely the code you tested? `$_POST` and `filter_input_array` do not know anything about JSON, so will not be populated; the `file_get_contents` and `json_decode` approach is the correct one.

Comment: @IMSoP I thank you for the answer.
I updated the image with the 3 outputs, the problem that none of the 3 returns the body of the call.

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself, I found the problem of the null answer.

In the headers I had disabled Content-Length.
Re-enabled, I now see the array populated in the response.
The code used in the php is

```
$test = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
var_dump($test);
```